# How to permanently update core-js

Tags: react-native

When trying to create a new react-native project I get an error. I have found solutions in the past that all function temporarily for a single project but I assume there has to be a more permanent solution.

The error message:

```
WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<2.6.5 is no longer maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3 or at least to actual version of core-js@2.
```

Comment: That's not an error message, it's a warning. You don't actually have to do anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

updating the `react-scripts` worked for me. run this command for yarn `yarn add react-scripts@latest` or `npm install react-scripts@latest` for npm

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if its permanent solution

```sh
npm install --save core-js@3
```

Also this link might be useful: https://babeljs.io/blog/2019/03/19/7.4.0

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add the essential parts from the 3rd party source directly to your answer for it might vanish at any time leaving your answer worthless (or worth less).